# How to match TSV columns starting with a prefix in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

I have a tsv file with the following columns

```
__label__baking __label__baking-powder __label__baking-soda __label__leavening How long can batter sit before chemical leaveners lose their power?
```

I have to match all columns that starts with `__label__` like `__label__baking` or `__label__baking-powder`, so they may have characters other than `[a-zA-Z]`, but not the prefix chars.

Here is a list of rows to try the regex:

```
 __label__flavor __label__spices __label__chemistry Flavor and Chemical Composition of Thyme
  __label__equipment What can I use as a manual hard cheese slicer?',
  __label__flour __label__milling Are stone or metal grinding wheels better for flour?
  __label__beans Do fava beans need to cook longer than other kinds of beans?
  __label__baking __label__bread __label__kneading Kneading Bread After Rising
  __label__beef __label__roast __label__gravy __label__roast-beef Extraordinary Beef Gravy?
  __label__baking __label__bread __label__crust How to heat up already baked french bread in oven to get a crispy crust
  __label__chocolate Is there a difference in appearance between semi and unsweetened chocolate?
```

In the case of one column I just did like

```
var label=text.match(/^[^\t]*/gm);
```

to match the first column, while on multiple columns I could do

```
var labels=row.split(/\t/)
```

but the N of columns with prefix is arbitrary and may vary.

Comment: [`__label__\S+`?](https://regex101.com/r/AMbZP2/2)

Comment: Are you sure that you need a regex? Won't something like `columns.split("\t").filter(label=>label.substr(0,9)==='__label__')` will help you?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/GN61LJ/1

Comment: Yes that's it! `columns.split(/\t/).filter(label=>label.substr(0,9)=='__label__')`, Thanks the filter helped here better than a different regex solution. What about performances when iterating over thousand of rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data =  `__label__flavor __label__spices __label__chemistry Flavor and Chemical Composition of Thyme
  __label__equipment What can I use as a manual hard cheese slicer?',
  __label__flour __label__milling Are stone or metal grinding wheels better for flour?
  __label__beans Do fava beans need to cook longer than other kinds of beans?
  __label__baking __label__bread __label__kneading Kneading Bread After Rising
  __label__beef __label__roast __label__gravy __label__roast-beef Extraordinary Beef Gravy?
  __label__baking __label__bread __label__crust How to heat up already baked french bread in oven to get a crispy crust
  __label__chocolate Is there a difference in appearance between semi and unsweetened chocolate?`;

var re = /\b__label__(.*?)\b/g;

console.log(data.match(re));
```

Comment: You have to match all labels like: `  __label__baking __label__bread __label__kneading` in a row...

Comment: @loretoparisi: It does match those. You mean you want separate sets per row? Maybe edit your question to show what the output should be.